# creating empty vector to push values into later

Tags: c++, stl, vector, dictionary

I have a `map<string,vector<string> >` called dict mapping a string to a list of strings. I want to assign empty values to the values of certain keys. something like this:

```
else dict[words[i]]=<EMPTY VECTOR WHERE I CAN PUSH DATA LATER INTO>;
```

words is a vector of strings. How do I do this? Using the Standard template library of course.

Comment: What behaviour do you want if `dict` already contains an element with a key equivalent to `words[i]`? (Or does the rest of your code make that impossible?)

Comment: if `dict` contains a key called `words[i]` then it pushes something in the vector associated with the key. Thats why theres an `else` in that statement. I thought providing the bits of code which don't really refer exactly to the problem I have been having would needlessly complicate things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`else dict[words[i]];` should be sufficient on its own. If `dict` does not yet contain any element with a key equivalent to `words[i]`, a new element will be created in `dict` with a copy of `words[i]` as the key and with a default constructed (empty) vector as the value.

If `dict` already contains an element equivalent to `words[i]`, then `dict` will not be modified.

Comment: It is sufficient, but the intent isn't necessarily very clear to the reader of the code.

Comment: `dict` is a `map`, which provides the `insert` function. `dict.insert( map<string,vector<string> >::value_type( words[i], vector<string>() );` is reasonably self-documenting, though the C++11 version is rather more succinct: `dict.insert( {words[i], {}} );` :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
dict[words[i]] = std::vector<std::string>();
```